# batch file failed and cannot copy file from one directory to another

Tags: batch-file

I created a test.bat program to copy a file from one directory to another. At first it ran well, but after I tested it few times it started to fail to copy! Is there something wrong with my `.bat` file?

The test.bat is in `D:\` and the 
  command in test.bat:

```
copy book_store_log.ldf C:\test
```

Comment: What is your error?! "File already exist"?

Comment: how to show the error message?

Comment: Don't double-click the batch file to run it, open commad prompt (_Start >> Run..._, type `cmd` and press *Enter*); in there, type `test.bat` and press *Enter*; after the batch file has finished execution, you'll see all the error messages...

Comment: ok, I'll try it.
Plus, my os is windows 10 , can that be a problem to run .bat?

Comment: It is encoding problem I should change it to ANSI

Comment: Perhaps you post your solution as an answer and accept it, so this question is closed?

Comment: yes it was closed, thank you

Comment: @Lilly a little off topic, but you should probably work on your English. For example, past tense.

Comment: oh, I will, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is encoding problem, I should change it to ANSI